# Highcharts how to make legends as data labels on scatter plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highcharts scatter plot, I want the marker to show the legend name instead of the data points, 
[image]

to this

[image]
how can I achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Here is  the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/3ovbw8m9/

```
 dataLabels: {
               enabled: true,
            allowOverlap:false,
                align: 'left',
                x:2,
                y:15
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a posible solution, you can add a formatter in the dataLabels

```
 formatter:function(){
                return this.series.name;
            }
```

and in the legend you can add

```
          labelFormatter: function () {
            //you can return something
            return '-';
        }
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jgonzalez315/885pobv6/2/

I hope this help!